# Firebase Chrome Extension Security via SSR

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm worried about storing Firebase Credentials of my app on the background script / popup script.
Especially for Firestore and storage.

Is it better to load content via an iFrame from a site where all the important stuff is Server Side Rendered for maximum security?

Or i'm I over thinking and minified JS is sufficient to secure the credentials ?